# Files form .py not reading into C

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

Lets say I have float x from main

```
import progC
def main():
     x = 3
     y=progC(x)
     print y

if __name__ == __main__
     main()
```

---

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* py_bracket(PyObject* self, float x){
    x = x+5;
    return Py_BuildValue("d",x);
}
```

ok problem is my float x in my C program receiving 0 not the number 3 from python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static PyObject* py_bracket(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    float x;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "f", &x))
        return NULL;
    x = x+5;
    return Py_BuildValue("f",x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem could be solved by using `int` instead of `float`. Python variables hold 12-bytes of memory by default and "C float" only hold 4. The second option is using the `PyTypeObject PyFloat_Type` that specifies that `float` type is required.